# Need help with hyperbolic geometry

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

The problem is

> In △ABC, it is given that $\operatorname{m}(\measuredangle ACB) = 90^\circ$ and $AC = BC$. Let $M$ be the midpoint
> of $AB$. Prove that $CM < AM$.

I know that you can prove this by contradiction, and I've already proved that $CM$ can't equal $AM$. I just need help proving that $CM$ is not greater than $AM$. I've drawn a diagram as a reference. This is hyperbolic geometry, by the way.

[image]

Comment: there is a Law of Sines...  Meanwhile, AMC  is a right angle, while  ACM is half a right angle. How big can angle CAM be?

Comment: I guess I would add to @WillJagy’s comment that the longer side is always opposite the larger angle.